# java.io.IOException: Waiting for startup of standalone server | MiniZooKeeperCluster

Tags: hadoop, apache-zookeeper, hbasetestingutility

I am trying to write some unit tests using HBaseTestingUtility. When I say startMiniCluster() on HBaseTestingUtility,

```
private HBaseTestingUtility hBaseTestingUtility = new HBaseTestingUtility(my_conf);
hBaseTestingUtility.startMiniCluster();
```

the execution fails with the following error.

```
java.io.IOException: Waiting for startup of standalone server

    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.MiniZooKeeperCluster.startup(MiniZooKeeperCluster.java:253)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseTestingUtility.startMiniZKCluster(HBaseTestingUtility.java:780)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseTestingUtility.startMiniZKCluster(HBaseTestingUtility.java:750)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseTestingUtility.startMiniCluster(HBaseTestingUtility.java:992)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseTestingUtility.startMiniCluster(HBaseTestingUtility.java:868)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseTestingUtility.startMiniCluster(HBaseTestingUtility.java:862)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseTestingUtility.startMiniCluster(HBaseTestingUtility.java:806)
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution.
Actually the MiniZooKeeperCluster was not able to execute the stat command because of which it was failing to continue. I set the following system property before the execution of the test cases.

```
System.setProperty("zookeeper.4lw.commands.whitelist", "stat");
```